# Spring 4 with Elasticsearch 5

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Is it possible to use elasticsearch server version 5 in combination with spring 4 (spring-data-elasticsearch)? 
So far if I use spring-data-elasticsearch 2.x, I can load the app, but get error `failed to get local cluster state`. 
If I include 3.x then I cannot start the app with error `Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError`...

I suceeded to connect using spring boot 2.x, but this one uses all spring libraries >5 which is currently not an option for me.

Comment: Did it compiles ?

Comment: It compiles without problem.

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For Elasticsearch 5.x you need to use Spring Data 3.x (Kay). Spring Boot 2.x uses that version, so that should work as you described it.

Taking a look at `spring-data-parent` there is an [explicit dependency on Spring 5.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-build/blob/master/parent/pom.xml#L110), so I don't think using Spring 4 will work; at least not without a lot of dependency wrangling. IMO the way forward will be to get to Spring 5 and then use Spring Data 3.